# Firefox dropdown menu click

Tags: html, firefox, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu for languages in my website and it works fine in Google Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer, but it is bugged in Firefox.

This is the code:

```
<a href="">
    <select id="languageSelector" style="background-color: transparent" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value=".">ESPAÑOL</option>
        <option value="./en/index.html">ENGLISH</option>
        <option value="./de/index.html">DEUTSCH</option>
        <option value="./fr/index.html">FRANÇAIS</option>
        <option value="./nl/index.html">NEDERLANDS</option>
    </select>
</a>
```

It also has a rare behaviour. If I move throught the select with my keyboard and I press Enter, it works, but clicking with the mouse is not working.

I'm using Firefox 38.0.5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/tudaqumabu/

Comment: could you provide the link for the code as well, not the output.jsbin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is your code surrounded by an a-Tag (`<a href=""></a>`) ?
If you click on the content (e.g. your dropdown) the href="" reload the page.
Remove the a or change `href=""` to `href="#"`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing href="" to href="#" was not enough. The href attribute must be eliminated altogether and just
    < a >
will be enough to:

1. make the DDL work correctly in FF 38.0.5
2. retain CSS classes linked
       to "a" in the stylesheet